# Boostrap - Gaps between columns

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I'm having trouble with bootstrap columns. I want to add gaps between column, but it doesnt work. You cann see in my snippet all the `.col-md-4` fill the `col-md-10` without space between. Here is my snippet :

```css
.col-md-4{background-color:red;}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="col-md-12">
  <div class="col-md-10">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4">Test</div>
      <div class="col-md-4">Test</div>
      <div class="col-md-4">Test</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You need to add some margins to the "test" divs. Bootstrap will not add this css styling for you.

Comment: Depending on what you want to achieve, you might also try using bootstrap's offset classes, like, <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-2">Test</div> Here's an example using the offset class & added margins. https://jsfiddle.net/uf077snc/1/   Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have an attached a [Codepen](https://codepen.io/Zlerp/pen/VzpNVj) to the best way i found to control the widths of the Gaps with bootstrap columns for Bootstrap v3 (fairly certain it works on Bootstrap v4 as well).

#### Whats wrong with your code??

first off you have a `col-md-12` wrapping `.col-md-10` without a parent container with a `row` class, so it's wrong by the Bootstrap standards in a big way. You should reference the Bootstrap 3 grid docs.

Controlling the gap/gutters is in the explanation below:

#### The Fix:

Boootstraps rows by default have a `margin-left` and `margin-right` of `-15px`, with their `col-*-*` columns having a `padding-left` and `padding-right` of `15px`. So to have complete control of the column gap sizes we simply match the negative margin on the `row`, to the padding on the `col-*-*`. Thus you can have extremely large or small gaps/gutters between the columns without it affecting the rest of the layout of your page.

Hope this helps!

https://codepen.io/Zlerp/pen/VzpNVj

Comment: @AlexCaron No problem! glad to help out!

Answer (score 0):

```
   <style>
    .back{
       background-color:red;
    }
</style>
<div class="col-md-12">
  <div class="col-md-10">
    <div class="row">
        <div class=" col-md-4  ">
            <div class="back" >Test</div>
        </div>
        <div class=" col-md-4   ">
             <div class="back" >Test</div>
        </div>
        <div class=" col-md-4  ">
             <div class="back" >Test</div>
        </div>
   </div>
 </div>
</div>
```